# multi thread memory error issue with infinite while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am having infinite loop waiting for messages, once i receive messages for example 30 seconds messages accumulated and dividing into chunks and processing it in parallel.

```
def process_data(data, i):
    #process data for chunks
   parsed_records = []
for msg in msgs:
    #just deleting unnecessary keys and few key data manipulated
    parsed_records.append(record_data)

name=f"sample_{rnd}.json"
with open(name, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(parsed_records)
    return True

while true:
    threads = []
    for n in range(len(num_of_chunks)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=process_data, args=(num_of_chunks[n], n))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    # Stop the threads
    for x in threads:
        t.join()
```

But, leading into MemoryError after few iterations.

Anything to be updated to avoid memory issue and work smoothly

Even i tried below code,

```
import multiprocessing
from faker import Faker
# Create Faker object to generate fake data for Producer
fake = Faker()

def myrandomdata(i,j):
    return fake.random_int(min = 1, max = j)

def divide_chunks(l, n):
    small_msgs = []
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        small_msgs.append(l[i:i + n])
    return small_msgs



def process_data(data, i):
        #process data for chunks
       parsed_records = []

    for msg in msgs:
        #just deleting unnecessary keys and few key data manipulated
        parsed_records.append(record_data)
    rnd = myrandomdata(1, 2000)
    name=f"sample_{rnd}.json"
    with open(name, "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(parsed_records)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__": 
     while true:

  #sample data
        msgs = [{"id":123,"min_position":7,"has_more_items":"true","items_html":"Bike","new_latent_count":3,"data":{"length":28,"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."},"numericalArray":[29,32,32,25,31],"StringArray":["Nitrogen","Carbon","Carbon","Carbon"],"multipleTypesArray":"true","objArray":[{"class":"middle","age":7},{"class":"middle","age":5},{"class":"lower","age":6},{"class":"upper","age":0},{"class":"middle","age":7}]},{"id":173,"min_position":7,"has_more_items":"true","items_html":"Bike","new_latent_count":3,"data":{"length":28,"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."},"numericalArray":[29,32,32,25,31],"StringArray":["Nitrogen","Carbon","Carbon","Carbon"],"multipleTypesArray":"true","objArray":[{"class":"middle","age":7},{"class":"middle","age":5},{"class":"lower","age":6},{"class":"upper","age":0},{"class":"middle","age":7}]},{"id":173,"min_position":7,"has_more_items":"true","items_html":"Bike","new_latent_count":3,"data":{"length":28,"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."},"numericalArray":[29,32,32,25,31],"StringArray":["Nitrogen","Carbon","Carbon","Carbon"],"multipleTypesArray":"true","objArray":[{"class":"middle","age":7},{"class":"middle","age":5},{"class":"lower","age":6},{"class":"upper","age":0},{"class":"middle","age":7}]},{"id":123,"min_position":7,"has_more_items":"true","items_html":"Bike","new_latent_count":3,"data":{"length":28,"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."},"numericalArray":[29,32,32,25,31],"StringArray":["Nitrogen","Carbon","Carbon","Carbon"],"multipleTypesArray":"true","objArray":[{"class":"middle","age":7},{"class":"middle","age":5},{"class":"lower","age":6},{"class":"upper","age":0},{"class":"middle","age":7}]},{"id":123,"min_position":7,"has_more_items":"true","items_html":"Bike","new_latent_count":3,"data":{"length":28,"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."},"numericalArray":[29,32,32,25,31],"StringArray":["Nitrogen","Carbon","Carbon","Carbon"],"multipleTypesArray":"true","objArray":[{"class":"middle","age":7},{"class":"middle","age":5},{"class":"lower","age":6},{"class":"upper","age":0},{"class":"middle","age":7}]}] 
    #msgs are nothing but bulk data recieving from server continuously am appending to msgs
        chunk_msgs = divide_chunks(msgs, 3)

    #clearing msgs to append next data after chunking previous data
        msgs.clear()
        with multiprocessing.Pool(len(chunk_msgs)) as pool:
        pool.starmap(process_data, [(chunk_msgs[n],n) for n in range(len(chunk_msgs))])
```

no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be creating the pool only once to avoid the repetitive creation and destruction of processes.
2. Assuming your processing is CPU-intensive, you should be creating a pool whose size is the number of CPU cores you have. Let's call this n_cores. Then you should split your msgs list into n_cores chunks where each chunk has approximately len(msgs) // n_cores messages. Your current divide_chunks method's n argument determines how many elements are in each chunk but it would be more convenient for it to specify the total number of chunks and let it figure out how many elements needs to be in each chunk.

```py
import multiprocessing

def divide_chunks(iterable, n):
    if type(iterable) is range and iterable.step != 1:
        # algorithm doesn't work with steps other than 1:
        iterable = list(iterable)
    l = len(iterable)
    n = min(l, n)
    k, m = divmod(l, n)
    return [iterable[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n)]

def process_data(chunk_number, msg_chunk):

    #process data for chunks
    try:
        for msg in msg_chunk:
            # data processing here according to my requirement
            # it may take 20-25 seconds of process that is why am planning for parallel
            # processing
            ...
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception", e)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only imports and function/class defs before this line.
    n_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n_cores) as pool:
        while True:
            # Process next list of messages:
            msgs = [...]
            chunks = divide_chunks(msgs, n_cores)
            msgs.clear()
            results = pool.starmap(process_data, enumerate(chunks))
```

**Update to Use Multithreading**

Read all the comments in the code and make sure you understand them!!!

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from threading import Lock

def divide_chunks(iterable, n):
    if type(iterable) is range and iterable.step != 1:
        # algorithm doesn't work with steps other than 1:
        iterable = list(iterable)
    l = len(iterable)
    n = min(l, n)
    k, m = divmod(l, n)
    return [iterable[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n)]

FILE_NO = 1
lock = Lock()

# What purpose does argument i serve? As long as you know ...
def process_data(i, msgs): # arguments must be in this order
    global FILE_NO

    #process data for chunks
    parsed_records = []

    for msg in msgs:
        #just deleting unnecessary keys and few key data manipulated
        parsed_records.append(record_data)

    # Get next file number
    # Do not use random number generator:
    with lock:
        file_no = FILE_NO
        FILE_NO += 1

    name = f"sample_{file_no}.json"
    with open(name, "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(parsed_records)

    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only imports and function/class defs before this line.
    # The number of chunks you want msgs split into
    # (this will be the number of files created for each invocation of process_data)
    # For now I wll assume a fixed value of 10. If this is not true, then set
    # POOL_SIZE to be what you think the maximum number of chunks you will have.
    # But note this: depending upon where you are creating your files, writing more than
    # one concurrently could hurt performance. This would be the case if you were, for example,
    # writing to a non-solid state drive.

    # Or recompute N_CHUNKS on each iteration based on size
    # of msgs:
    N_CHUNKS = 10
    POOL_SIZE = N_CHUNKS
    with ThreadPool(POOL_SIZE) as pool:
        while True:
            # Process next list of messages:
            msgs = [...]
            chunks = divide_chunks(msgs, N_CHUNKS)
            msgs.clear()
            results = pool.starmap(process_data, enumerate(chunks))
```

Comment: thanks. Am getting messages continuously from server and am dividing the messages into smaller chunks. and am passing smaller chunks into threads to process it in parallel. But, am waiting for 30 seconds window to accumulate messages in that 30 seconds. But, for 2 or 3 times working perfectly but then getting MemoryError

Comment: If this did not correct your problem, you need to post a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: i have added sample json.. i may get some 75K records i will chunk those by divding them into smaller chunks

Comment: Can you please suggest me where am doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think there is enough info here to determine what's causing your error with what uou have posted (and you have indentation errors). You should look at the stack trace to see where its occurring and if it is not in code you have posted, you need to update the post again. But a few suggestions having nothing to do with your error: If `process_data` is CPU-intensive, then your pool size should just be the number of cores you have (multiprocessing.cpu_count()`. `starmap` does its own chunking so you may not need to. Also you should not be creating the pool in the `while True:` loop. But ..

Comment: You say it takes 20 to 25 seconds for each invocation of `process_data`. But how often do messages come in? That is, are messages arriving faster than you can process them? How large does `msgs` get?

Comment: Am new to stackoverflow. so indentation errors while posting my code. Sorry for that. Process_data will take json as input, do some processing and store into file. for ex: 1st 30 seconds window am getting 75K length of json, it will chunk into 8 chunks by didving into 10000 and processs it. it is working fine.. but when we go for second set of data for next 30 seconds data.. again am getting some 90K records. am dividing by 10K and getting 10 chuck files... no issues.. next 30 seconds data, i.e another 80K records i got and am processing into 10 chunks.. now am facing Memory error

Comment: am new to both multithread and multiprocess pool concepts.. so please help me @ Booboo

Comment: messages may come continuously.. i may get 60K or 90K or 76K records

Comment: for ex: 1st 30 seconds window am getting 75K length of json, it will chunk into 8 chunks by didving with 10K and processs it. it is working fine.. but when we go for second set of data for next 30 seconds data.. again am getting some 90K records. am dividing by 10K and getting 9 chunk files... no issues.. next 30 seconds data, i.e another 80K records i got and am processing into 8 chunks.. for third iteration am facing Memory error

Comment: See my update. I have nothing else to offer.

Comment: I just did another update to use method `imap`.

Comment: Still am getting Memory error with starmap...  :(

Comment: File "C:\Users\asd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError

Comment: I think you are going to have to post *minimal* code that produced this error -- you cannot leave `process_data` unspecified as you have been doing. Reduce this function to the minimum that still has the error and update your question with this. And publish the **complete** stack trace in your question.

Comment: can we move to discussion?

Comment: i have updated the process_data with my snippet. Please check

Comment: What is the value of `rnd` in `name=f"sample_{rnd}.json"``. I assume each invocation of `process_data` is creating separate files but how is this done? A random number? And why does each invocation take 20 - 30 seconds if all you are doing is very little CPU processing and you are not writing out very much data?

Comment: myrandomdata -> am using this function via faker import

Comment: Why would `process_data` take 20 - 30 seconds if all you are doing is very little CPU processing and you are not writing out very much data?

Comment: am writing into multiple places like local server and cloud storage

Comment: Also, instead of generating a random number, why don't you just use passed argument *i*. And could all of the data be written to a single file instead of N different files?

Comment: I need to see *exactly* what you are doing. Again: I don't understand how simply removing a few keys form dictionaries and writing out data takes 20 - 30 seconds.

Comment: requirement is to write into N different files.

Comment: please suggest me some good approach to make this run smooth

Comment: There are just too many details not specified that it is becoming a waste of your time (and mine).. I think you now need to bring a consultant in-house to review all of your code and understand all of your processing requirements. But it seems to me that what you are doing is mostly I/O processing, then I would think this could be better done with multithreading -- I will update source for this.

Comment: See update and and call in a consultant.

Comment: basically its memory usage getting increased iteration by iteration

Comment: So, any help in avoiding memory usage @Booboo ?