# Memory Usage getting increased for every iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

Here is my code,

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from threading import Lock

def divide_chunks(iterable, n):
    if type(iterable) is range and iterable.step != 1:
        # algorithm doesn't work with steps other than 1:
        iterable = list(iterable)
    l = len(iterable)
    n = min(l, n)
    k, m = divmod(l, n)
    return [iterable[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n)]

FILE_NO = 1
lock = Lock()

def process_data(i, msgs): # arguments must be in this order
    global FILE_NO

    #process data for chunks
    parsed_records = []

    for msg in msgs:
        #just deleting unnecessary keys and few key data manipulated
        #assigning processed msgs to record_data 
        parsed_records.append(record_data)

    # Get next file number
    with lock:
        file_no = FILE_NO
        FILE_NO += 1

    name = f"sample_{file_no}.json"
    with open(name, "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(parsed_records)

    return True

    if __name__ == "__main__":  # only imports and function/class defs before this line.
        # The number of chunks you want msgs split into
        # (this will be the number of files created for each invocation of process_data)
        N_CHUNKS = 10
        POOL_SIZE = N_CHUNKS
        with ThreadPool(POOL_SIZE) as pool:
            while True:
                 # Process next list of messages:
                msgs = [...]
                chunks = divide_chunks(msgs, N_CHUNKS)
                msgs.clear()
                results = pool.starmap(process_data, enumerate(chunks))
```

for ex: 1st 30 seconds window am getting 75K length of json, it will chunk into N chunks by diving with X and process it. it is working fine.. but when we go for second set of data for next 30 seconds data.. again am getting some 90K records. am dividing by X and getting N chunk files... no issues.. next 30 seconds data, i.e another 80K records i got and am processing into N chunks.. for third iteration am facing Memory error

how to avoid memory usage issue?

Comment: Where does `record_data` comes from?

Comment: in process_data am appending to record data after some operations on chunk of messages @farshad

Comment: i have updated with comment in code @farshad.

Comment: Other than `parsed_records`, I could not find any incremental object that might hog the memory. Maybe other will be able to help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: This is just a resubmission of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220914/multi-thread-memory-error-issue-with-infinite-while-loop). What hasn't changed is that you have not provided enough details in your over-simplified `process_data` function to be able to determine where the problem is. Provide a *simple*, complete yet minimal, reproducible example with dummy data and the actual processing of that data that demonstrates the error.

Comment: For example, see [this program](https://ideone.com/FKlSOS) where I have provided dummy data and processing of the passed data. It will not run in that environment purposely since I am using a `tqdm` progress bar, which is not part of the standard library. But you can copy it and run it and you will see that it does 5 iterations very quickly with no problem. What must be changed in this program to cause a memory error? Update your question accordingly!

Comment: Actually, i used profiler library and debug the error. for every iteration memory usage growing and leading to memory error

Comment: Can you help me to prevent memory usage